# Benefits of using namespace alias over preprocessor

Tags: c++, namespaces, c-preprocessor

What are the benefits of `namespace alias` over `#define`?

```
namespace NS1{
    namespace NS2 {
        namespace NS3
        {
            void fun() {
                std::cout << "Understanding namespace alias\n";
            }
        }
    }
}

#define NS NS1::NS2::NS3
//over
namespace NS=NS1::NS2::NS3;
```

Comment: at least always the general advantages of not using macros that you can find in dozens or hundred of questions here: macros dont know namespaces, scopes etc.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the benefits of namespace alias over #define?

The generic disadvantage of defines applies here: the pre-processor replaces the source before compilation, which leads to a number of (bigger or smaller) problems:

- attempting to use `NS::fun` in the debugger will cause the debugger to tell you there is no NS namespace (because the compiler never actually saw the symbol).
- error messages caused by entities within the namespace, will yield error messages with tokens that simply cannot be found in the source code (no matter how you search) unless you know (in your client code) that you're not looking at a namespace, but at a define looking like a namespace.

Aditionally, `#define`-d symbols do not belong to namspaces. This means that once you `#define NS`, you will be unable to have a NS symbol anywhere else in your source code (because your pre-compiler will play switcheroo with it without saying anything). That means you cannot say:

```
namespace client_code // namespace where NS should not be visible
{
    int NS = 0; // compiler tries to compile "int NS1::NS2::NS3 = 0;",
                // knowing that NS3 is a namespace
}
```

If the client code is your own, that's not a problem, as you can simply avoid the name (though there is no excuse for why you should have to).

If you're writing header files / libraries that anyone else will use, at the very least you should provide a list of known limitations to it, where you say "client code cannot use these and these names".

Answer (score 3):

When using an alias the NS symbol become known to the compiler, while using a macro it will replace the string whenever it can find it. So if you happen to have a local variable named NS it will replace it with NS1::NS2::NS3 which is hardly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what daramarak has said, the namespace alias will respect *syntax* and *semantics*; the `#define` will not. The namespace alias will only ever kick in when the compiler encounters something like `NS::func()`, the `#define` on the other hand is an entirely blunt tool and will also recognise and mangle statements like `NS()` or `int NS=7` or, even, `namespace NS=NS1::NS2::NS3`. And, believe me, when it does mangle it you will get utterly confusing error messages.